# Why is Python not responding when I select the quit button in a simple tkinter example?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to learn how to incorporate various types of graphs in tkinter As a simple example, I tried using what's posted at

```
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html
```

I using Python 3.7 within Spyder 4.1.2 on a Mac (OS Catalina 10.15.4).

For purposes of completeness, here's the code, although I've added a second plot using the subplot command:

```
 import numpy as np
 import tkinter as tk

 from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
     FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
 # Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
 from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
 from matplotlib.figure import Figure


 root = tk.Tk()
 root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

 fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
 t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
 fig.add_subplot(1,2,1).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))
 fig.add_subplot(1,2,2).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(6 * np.pi * t))

 canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
 canvas.draw()
 canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

 toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
 toolbar.update()
 canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


 def on_key_press(event):
     print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
     key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


 canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)


 def _quit():
     root.quit()     # stops mainloop
     root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent


 button = tk.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
 button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

 tk.mainloop()
```

My two graphs are created just as I hoped on the canvas. However, when I select he Quit button, the window does not close. Instead, I'm told Python is not responding, and I have to do a Force Quit.

Comment: It works just fine on my computer. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Just Spyder, which comes bundled with Anaconda.

Comment: I'm running VS code and it worked perfectly fine. I hate to say this but I had a similar issue awhile back. Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: Also worked in Thonny another IDE

Comment: I did restart my computer. No change.

Comment: Try calling `matplotlib.pyplot.close('all')` inside `_quit()`.

Comment: Thanks--that didn't work either.

Second time I've had issues using tkinter and Spyder. I'm switching IDEs, likely IDLE.